# Start Menu right-click "Properties" option missing from Program entries in Lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: lubuntu

In Lubuntu 13.10, when you right-click on any Start Menu program entry, such as Firefox or Audacious, you have two options: "Add to Desktop" and "Properties". In Lubuntu 14.04, the "Properties" option is missing. Is there any way to get the "Properties" option back in Lubuntu 14.04? Why was it removed? Or is my Start Menu configuration all messed up?

Please advise if possible. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: something is wrong with your start menu config - looks ok on my fresh lubuntu 14.04 install.  Not sure what though.  If you create a new user do you have the same issue?

Comment: I tried Lubuntu without installing. The Properties option does appear under each Start Menu Program entry. However it does not function at all. When you right-click on it, nothing happens. The only option that works is the Add To Desktop. If you could please check to see if it works for you. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to reconfigure the Start Menu?

Comment: Properties displays the File-Properties window as expected.  Since you've tried lubuntu as a live CD and it is not working for you, I would suggest you file a bug report to allow the developers visibility of the issue.

Comment: How do I file a bug report? I cannot find any emails to contact any of the Lubuntu Developers. As of right now I do not have a "Properties" option for any Start Menu Program entry. It is completely missing. Before I completed all the updates, when it was available, nothing happened when I clicked on it, except the whole Start Menu froze. The Add To Desktop is present and works fine. I wish I could get 14.04 to work as well as 13.10. I never had any of these problems with 13.10, which ran beautifully.

Comment: Use this Q&A to send a bug-report: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: Thank you! However if you are able to display the File-Properties window as expected then the issue appears to be with my Computer. I have an older P4 with Intel Graphics. Probably a conflict with the new kernel. However I did not have any problems with 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this bug, Properties shows up but nothing happens, fresh install of Lubuntu 14.04. Very disappointed in this release, a multitude of bugs especially for stable.

Comment: -1: This is not an answer.

Comment: Apparently the Lubuntu Developers are aware of this bug. At least from what I have been informed they are aware of it. I have still not been able to contact any of the Lubuntu Developers directly. I have been advised to re-download Lubuntu 13.10 until the 14.04 bugs are fixed as 13.10 has two more months of updates before end-of-life.

Comment: I re-installed Lubuntu on May 11 and it does appear this specific bug has been fixed, along with several other bugs. No error messages of any kind upon install nor even when updating. Everything is working terrific so far.